# multi-threaded data processing pipeline with spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-data, spring-integration

I have an application that receives data packages and need to parse, transform and store this data.

To increase throughput, I'm trying to place various steps into separate threads and let the data 'flow' through `BlockingQueue`s between them.

Something like:

(A) --> (B) --> (C) --> ...

So far I let A, B, C implement `Runnable` and create them manually, providing the input/output queues in the constructors.

Problem is, I need access to Spring services in A,B,C. 
So I annotated A, B, C with `@Component` and `@Scope("prototype")`. I have them injected into another Service that than creates and sets the queues between them, calling `thread.start(..)`

Is there a better, more 'Spring-like' way of doing this? And, how can I control the destruction of the components, ideally letting them finish their current input queue?

EDIT 1:
I followed Edwin Dalorzos advice and played around with spring integration, trying to archive my idea of one thread per message endpoint. I got the multi-threading working, but can't limit the number of threads per endpoint. 
Created a little demo at https://github.com/taseroth/spring-integration-multithreaded

Comment: What you're doing sounds pretty much like a work for [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/). Every endpoint is communicate through channels, and you can use blocking queues as channels and make sure every one runs in a separate thread.

Comment: There's a better, much better, you should know that.

Comment: Why are processing components runnables that flow? Usually components are the static things that manage threads and data, and the data is what flows between them

Comment: @zapl: perhaps I was not clear enough. Of course the data is flowing between the components,  not the other way around.

Comment: @nipon: can you give me a pointer? I would not ask if I would know

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo:  interesting option, but I hope for a more lightweight solution, as this is only a small part of the application.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo : I played around with spring integration. created a sample app with a blocking queue and and an creator / receiver. There are multiple treads running; fine. But I want 1 thread per message endpoint. haven't found anything in the documentation so far

Comment: What about Asynchronous service? [https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

Comment: @bert Here's [a small example](https://github.com/edalorzo/spring-int-exp) I did with Spring integration. Every endpoint runs on a different thread.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: can you put this into an answer so I can accept? After you initial suggestion, I came up with something similar, although I defined one executor (with fixed poll size = 1) for each message endpoint. seems to do the trick ;-)

Comment: A BlockingQueue won't regulate the number of pending tasks. If you are using a executorService, it it can't create a new task, the task is discarded. There are several solutions. You can google them using the term blockingExecutor